# MainActivity does not open before connection is made in application class Android App

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create a chat application in android, just started learning .Its almost done how I wanted.
However, there are two things I want to solve to make it better.

1. Right now, I have an application class which has a thread to make connection to the server.Due to this, MainActivity layout does not shows up when  the server is offline.It just shows a white screen. I can see from logs it is trying to connect to the server. Is it possible to show the MainActivity even if server is offline ?
2. How can I monitor my connection to the server ? For eg, during using the application, if server goes offline, client app crashes. Is there a way to stop that ? What I want to do is, if server crashes, client will keep trying to connect to server again.

Below is my code that I am working on now ( MainActivity & Application Class)

MyApplication.java

```
package com.niyaz.chataway;

public class Myapplication extends Application {
    public static boolean isfirstrun;
    public static Thread rthread,connectionthread;
    public static Socket socket;
    public static int SERVER_PORT;
    public static String SERVER_IP;
    public static BufferedReader br;
    public static BufferedWriter bw;
    public static String serverresponse;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();
        SERVER_IP = "192.168.1.116";
        SERVER_PORT= 62000;
        isfirstrun=true;
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }

        connectionthread = new connection(socket,SERVER_IP,SERVER_PORT);
       // connectionthread.start();
        connectionthread.run();

        rthread = new receive(this,socket,br);
        rthread.start();
    }

    public static void sendmessage(String message){
        try {
            bw.write(message);
            bw.newLine();
            bw.flush();
            System.out.println("Sent : " + message);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

class connection extends Thread{
    private Socket socket;
    private String serverip;
    private int serverport;

    public connection(Socket socket,String Serverip,int serverport){
        this.socket=socket;
        this.serverip=Serverip;
        this.serverport=serverport;
    }

    public void run(){
        while (true){
            try {
                socket = new Socket(serverip,serverport);
                System.out.println("Connection Established");
                bw= new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
                br= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                break;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

class receive extends Thread{
    private Socket socket;
    private BufferedReader br;
    private Handler handler = new Handler();
    String message;
    private Context context;
    public receive(Context context, Socket socket, BufferedReader br){
        this.socket = socket;
        this.br = br;
        this.context=context;
    }

    public void run(){
        while (true) {
            try {
                message = br.readLine().toString();
                System.out.println("Received message : " + message);
                StringTokenizer token = new StringTokenizer(message, "|");
                String a = token.nextToken();
                String b = token.nextToken();
                String c = token.nextToken();
                switch (a) {
                    case "1": // get true or false from server
                        synchronized (this) {
                            MainActivity.response = b;
                            notify();
                            System.out.println("notified");
                        }
                        break;
                    case "2": // get group list from server
                        synchronized (this) {
                            System.out.println(b);
                            if (b.equals("end")){
                                notify();
                                System.out.println("notified");
                                break;
                            }
                            group.all_groups.add(b);
                        }

                        break;
                    case "3": // get users in the group
                        synchronized (this) {
                            System.out.println(b);
                            if (b.equals("end")){
                                notify();
                                System.out.println("notified");
                                break;
                            }
                            group.buffer.append(b);
                            group.buffer.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));

                        }
                        break;
                    case "4":// get group size
                        synchronized (this) {
                            group.groupsize = Integer.valueOf(b);
                            notify();
                            System.out.println("notified");
                        }
                        break;
                    case "5": //  get chat messages from dB
                        synchronized (this) {
                            System.out.println(b);
                            if (b.equals("end")){
                                notify();
                                System.out.println("notified");
                                break;
                            }
                            group.chatlist.add(b);
                        }

                        break;
                    case "6":// receive real time chat
                        final String temp = b;
                        final String t = c;
                        synchronized (this){
                            System.out.println("group_array.size()"+group.group_array.size());

                            for (int k = 0;k<group.group_array.size();k++){
                                if (c.equals(group.group_array.get(k))){
                                    System.out.println(chatpage.checkactivity);
                                    if (chatpage.checkactivity){
                                        handler.post(new Runnable() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void run() {
                                                chatpage.adapter.add(temp);
                                            }
                                        });
                                        break;
                                    }
                                    if (!chatpage.checkactivity) {
                                        handler.post(new Runnable() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void run() {
                                              //  Toast.makeText(context,"new message",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.m);
                                                mp.start();


                                                NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
                                                builder.setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.sym_action_chat);
                                                Intent intent = new Intent(context, group.class);
                                                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
                                                builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
                                                builder.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.logo));
                                                builder.setContentTitle("New Message");
                                                builder.setContentText(temp);
                                                NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                                                notificationManager.notify(1, builder.build());


                                            }
                                        });

                                        ArrayList<String> temp_array = new ArrayList<>();
                                        temp_array = group.map.get(c);
                                        temp_array.add(temp);
                                        group.map.put(c,temp_array);

                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        break;
                    case "7":{   // get response from server
                        synchronized (this) {
                            serverresponse = b;
                            notify();
                            System.out.println("notified");
                        }

                        break;
                    }
                    case "8":{   // check if group already exist
                        synchronized (this) {
                            group.groupstatus = b;
                            notify();
                            System.out.println("notified");
                        }

                        break;
                    }
                    case "9": // get user grouplist

                        synchronized (this) {
                            System.out.println(b);
                            if (b.equals("end")){
                                notify();
                                System.out.println("notified");
                                break;
                            }
                            group.group_array.add(b);
                        }

                        break;
                    default:
                        System.out.println("Why I am in default ??");
                        break;
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.niyaz.chataway;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button login, register;
    EditText uname,upass;
    Myapplication myapplication;
    public static String response,name,password;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        uname=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.uname);
        upass=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.upass);
        login=(Button)findViewById(R.id.login);
        register=(Button)findViewById(R.id.register);
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        myapplication.isfirstrun=true;
        group.group_array = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void onclickmain(View view){
        Button b= (Button)view;
        name = uname.getText().toString();
        password=upass.getText().toString();

        if (b.getId()==R.id.login){
            if (name.isEmpty() || password.isEmpty()){
                Toast.makeText(this,"User name or password cannot be blank",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
            }
            else {
                myapplication.sendmessage("1|" + name + "|" + password + "|" + null);
                synchronized (myapplication.rthread){
                    try {
                        myapplication.rthread.wait();
                        System.out.println(response);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                if (response.equals("true")){
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),group.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Username & Password do not match !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }

        else if (b.getId()==R.id.register){
            if (name.isEmpty() || password.isEmpty()){
                Toast.makeText(this,"User name or password cannot be blank", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
            }
            else {
                myapplication.sendmessage("2|" + name + "|" + password + "|" + null);
                synchronized (myapplication.rthread){
                    try {
                        myapplication.rthread.wait();
                        System.out.println(myapplication.serverresponse);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                if (myapplication.serverresponse.equals("true")){
                    Toast.makeText(this, "User Registered Successfully !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Try Again with different username !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For my 2nd question, i added the below in my code.Now my app reconnects if there is a server downtime.

```js
if( (message=br.readLine())==null){
                  handler.post(new Runnable() {
                      @Override
                      public void run() {
                          try {
                              bw.close();
                              br.close();
                          } catch (IOException e) {
                              e.printStackTrace();
                          }
                          toolbar_group.setSubtitle("Network Down !");
                          connectionthread.run();
                      }
                  });
                  return;
              }
```

However, the below is only called after the connection is back up.

```js
 toolbar_group.setSubtitle("Network Down !");
```

I want a way to show the user that connection is down, please wait for connection to be back up.
Could you suggest something ?
Btw thanks a lot for the prompt reply.I am looking into services.For now, this would solve my problem.

Comment: I suggest spawning the connection thread in `MainActivity` instead of extending `Application`. The later option is considered a code smell. You should also learn about `AsyncTask` for multithreading. It handles a lot of the details for you.

Comment: `static` methods and variables are also considered a bad practice as they are not very Object Oriented friendly. They certainly have uses. However, you need to learn object oriented concepts before truly understand when using `static`s is justified.

Comment: Start your server connection in main activity, use a `Service` to keep the connection in the background, read about Services on Android. Control your service from your Activity (bind it if you want). Read about all that. Don't use Static fields unless you have a good reason, you don't here. Use `Log.d` (or similar) instead of System.out.println. Etc.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid polluting the question with a million comments, I'll summarize some good points and give you some reference material.

1. Don't start your connection thread in Application. There are numerous reasons behind this.
2. Use AsyncTask if you need to multi-thread, but learn about the various pitfalls (vs. blindly using AsyncTask for everything). Remember, it keeps a reference to your activity, so you can leak a lot of memory if improperly used.
3. Don't use `static` fields, methods, etc. unless you really have a good reason to do so; I haven't seen one in your code yet. Learn and read about static's memory implications and multi-threading too.
4. Read about Android `Service`s.
5. Use `Log.` vs. `println`.
6. By *more or less Google's convention*, prefix your private fields with `m` (I don't like this, but I do it for the sake of consistency), so `response` becomes `mResponse`.

Some reading material:

1. [Application Fundamentals](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fundamentals.html)
2. [Services](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)
3. [Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html)
4. [Processes and Threads](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html)

Start with those, and improve your Android Skills ;-) Take your time.